# ActionScript 3.0 adding node to XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

i have

```
<myXML>
</myXML>
```

using

```
myXML.appendChild(<bla>text</bla>);
```

i get

```
<myXML>
  <bla>text</bla>
</myXML>
```

but how to do it if 'text' is actually something contained in a string variable? so how do i add a childnode that has some programmatically generated content?

so i have:

```
var myXML:XML = <myXML><myXML>
var myString:String = "Hello World"
```

i want to do something like

```
myXML.appendChild(<bla>mySring</bla>);
```

how to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use the `{}` notation:

```
var myXML:XML = <myXML/>
var myString:String = "Hello World"
//...
myXML.appendChild(<bla>{myString}</bla>)
```

**Update 1:**

If you want to use the `CDATA` inside your string you can convert it to an XML node, and then add it to your current XML:

```
var myXML:XML = <myXML/>
var myString:String = "<![CDATA[Hello World]]>"
//...
myXML.appendChild(<bla>{new XML(myString)}</bla>)
```

Comment: oh that's great - thanks! how to do it if my String contains '<![CDATA[...]]>' ?

Comment: @Mat i have updated the answer. If you have other question you should accept one of these answers and then open a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close Mat, just missing a node to append to:

```
var myString:String = 'Hello World';
//this does not work
//var xml:XML = <myXML>myString</myXML>; 
//this works
var myXML:XML = <myXML />.appendChild(myString);
//test
trace(myXML,myXML.toXMLString());
```

It would nice if the value stored in myString would go straight into an XML declaration, without the need to appendChild.

Using your extra node(bla), you simply append the string variable to that node:

```
var myString:String = 'Hello World';
var myXML:XML = <myXML><bla /></myXML>;
myXML.bla.appendChild(myString);
//test
trace(myXML);
```

Comment: mmmh - but how to do it such that the result will be `<myXML><bla>Hello World</bla></myXML>`?